# Each paragraph next to each image

Tags: html, css, image, text

I have 4 different paragraphs and 4 images which each correspond to each image. I would like to have each paragraph right next to each image.

Any help welcome, please

```css
body{
    background-image:url(http://www.icotoken.tel/images/slider_slide_5.jpg)
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.bigger{
    padding: 30px;
    height: 300px;
}
.text {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 950px;
    max-width: 950px;
}
.img{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class= "text">
    <div><img class = "img" src = "https://www.gaincontact.com/files/2016/10/Globelanguageshomepage-1.jpg" align= "left">
    <p>1st Paragraph</p></div>
    <div><img class = "img" src = "https://img00.deviantart.net/c3e2/i/2015/136/f/a/rinne_rokudou_rokumon__kyoukai_no_rinne_minimalism_by_greenmapple17-d8tm8om.png" align= "right">
    <p>2nd Paragraph</p></div>
    <div><img class = "img" src = "http://smart-defence.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/art.jpg" align="left">
    <p>3rd Paragraph</p></div>
    <div><img class = "img" src = "https://www.markchadwick.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Spin-Painting-18-1000x643.jpg" align="right"> . 
    <p>4th Paragraph</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to add `overflow: hidden` to each `div`:

```
.text > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Look at the below snippet:

```css
body{
    background-image:url(http://www.icotoken.tel/images/slider_slide_5.jpg)
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.bigger{
    padding: 30px;
    height: 300px;
}
.text {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 950px;
    max-width: 950px;
}
.img{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.text > div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class= "text">
    <div><img class = "img" src = "https://www.gaincontact.com/files/2016/10/Globelanguageshomepage-1.jpg" align= "left">
    <p>1st Paragraph</p></div>
    <div><img class = "img" src = "https://img00.deviantart.net/c3e2/i/2015/136/f/a/rinne_rokudou_rokumon__kyoukai_no_rinne_minimalism_by_greenmapple17-d8tm8om.png" align= "right">
    <p>2nd Paragraph</p></div>
    <div><img class = "img" src = "http://smart-defence.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/art.jpg" align="left">
    <p>3rd Paragraph</p></div>
    <div><img class = "img" src = "https://www.markchadwick.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Spin-Painting-18-1000x643.jpg" align="right"> . 
    <p>4th Paragraph</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll take this chance to ask you also if it is possible to have each text in the middle

Comment: It's easy using flexbox model. Please look at @StefanBob answer and just add `align-items: center;` to the following `.text > div`

Comment: It doesn't give the result I expect, I mean rather than having the text in the middle at the top, I hope to have it in the middle at the center

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. And is there a code while using ```.text > div {overflow: hidden;}```?

Comment: @Louisff9 Yeah, there are some tricks to do that keeping `overflow: hidden`, but it's much more complicated. Do you really need it? :)

Answer (score 0):

I just put `display: flex`; on each `.text > div`, which just properly formats the image and text next to each other.

For further positioning check out flexbox

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://www.icotoken.tel/images/slider_slide_5.jpg)     background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.bigger {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 300px;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 950px;
  max-width: 950px;
}

.img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.text > div {
  display: flex;
}

.text > div:nth-of-type(odd) img {
  order: 2;
}

.text > div:nth-of-type(odd) p {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div><img class="img" src="https://www.gaincontact.com/files/2016/10/Globelanguageshomepage-1.jpg" align="left">
    <p>1st Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div><img class="img" src="https://img00.deviantart.net/c3e2/i/2015/136/f/a/rinne_rokudou_rokumon__kyoukai_no_rinne_minimalism_by_greenmapple17-d8tm8om.png" align="right">
    <p>2nd Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div><img class="img" src="http://smart-defence.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/art.jpg" align="left">
    <p>3rd Paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div><img class="img" src="https://www.markchadwick.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Spin-Painting-18-1000x643.jpg" align="right"> .
    <p>4th Paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It breaks the images alignment (left, right, left, right)

Comment: You could either just change the html position of the image and p, just switch order every other element. Or with flexbox you could do something like .text > div:nth-of-type(odd) img { order: 2 } and same thing with the odd div p { order: 1 }

Comment: Yes, the author of the post could do that, but it would be easier to just add `overflow: hidden` to those `div`'s

Comment: Hmm yea he could do that too... but then that wouldn't do anything and doesn't solve anything... so why would he do that

Comment: If you have another solution, post an answer Alex M

Comment: Oh nice, way to work with the way he was trying to do it

Comment: Yeah, flexbox model is a powerful thing, but given what he's done.. The final decision is up to him

Comment: I would suggest that you update your solution according to your first comment. It's worth seeing.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks and sorry for initial snootiness, you clearly know what you're talking about. I'm extremely guilty of imposing flexbox on everyone